# O que são módulos?

Tags: java, organização-de-projeto

Sempre que leio sobre Java 9, vejo afirmações de que a grande mudança na próxima versão do Java será o suporte nativo a módulos através do [Projeto Jigsaw](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/).

Logo em seguida, vêm as críticas à adoção de um novo padrão para módulos em vez do OSGi, que, pelo que entendo, seria o padrão *de facto* para módulos em Java e, por ser amplamente adotado, deveria ser parte do JDK 9 em vez do Jigsaw.

A questão é: até onde eu sei, eu nunca vi nem usei OSGi (apesar de que, admito, nunca participei de um projeto grande em Java que não fosse Android), mas sempre vejo opções de módulos em IDEs como o IntelliJ para Java 8 e anteriores, e já importei módulos para projetos do Android Studio. O que ocorre? O IntelliJ tem seu próprio conceito de módulos? Alguma IDE popular dá suporte ao OSGi?

Além disso, de grosso modo, quando eu sei que uma parte do meu projeto Java deveria se tornar um módulo e não um pacote? As duas coisas estão relacionadas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Java e seus "padrões"

O Java é campeão em deturpar padrões, para o bem ou para o mau.

Quando o Hibernate popularizou ORMs em Java, foi criado o padrão JPA. Sua adoção ocorreu gradualmente e até certo ponto a API é mais bem feita (eu prefiro) do que a API do Hibernate. Porém o padrão nunca foi e nunca será páreo para os frameworks, pois ele não prevê todas as situações e muitas vezes você precisa usar extensões que não são portáveis.

Quando o Joda-Time estava fazendo muito sucesso, sendo a referência de como implementar rotinas que envolvem data, hora e toda sorte de bichos relacionados a calendários, o Java 8 introduziu a API `java.time`. Mais uma vez, o escopo é mais limitado e a adoção está sendo bem gradual, afinal a maioria dos frameworks (mesmo no JEE) ainda trabalha com `java.util.Date` e muita gente nem sabe que existe um `java.time.LocalDateTime`.

Quando o Spring dominava IoC e outras alternativas populares como Google Guice surgiram, eis que o Java introduziu o CDI.

Quando programação funcional em Java era feita usando Google Guava, alguma outra biblioteca específica, eis que foi criado a API `java.util.stream`.

Em todos os casos, a adoção é extremamente gradual. Muita gente nem fica sabendo das novidades, outras estão acostumados com alguma API e não migram,simplesmente não tem condições de migrar um sistema complexo, não veem vantagem ou ainda ficam impedidos por alguma limitação da API que mal saiu e já tem promessa de ter tais e tais recursos adicionados na próxima versão.

## JigSaw vs. OSGi

OSGi é o padrão por já existir há mais de uma década. Infelizmente, é também [bem complexo e de difícil adoção](http://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/news-dev/osgi-no-thanks/). Além disso, para a maioria das aplicações, os ganhos com o uso de OSGi seriam menores do que o custo ou simplesmente ele [não agrega nada de valor](http://blog.caucho.com/2009/06/15/why-osgi-is-cool-but-not-for-most-enterprise-apps/).

Por outro lado, ao que parece os módulos como propostos pelo projeto JigSaw são mais simples de entender, pelo menos no uso mais comum, e a implementação mais fácil.

Não farei um comparativo de funcionalidades, pois não sou especialista nas duas, mas no geral parece que o JigSaw tem um escopo mais limitado em sua primeira versão.

É impossível prever, mas neste caso específico acredito que a adoção do uso de módulos será mais acelerado pelos seguintes motivos:

1. Pouca gente usa OSGi
2. Quem usa OSGi nem sempre está contente e não precisa de todos os recursos
3. Módulos são mais fáceis de entender
4. Módulos estarão disponíveis em todas as plataformas, enquanto  OSGi precisa de um framework e todos os componentes compatíveis com esse framework

## Quem usa OSGi

Não tenho muitos exemplos, mas o Eclipse é o melhor e mais conhecido. Todos os módulos da IDE e seus plugins são módulos OSGi. Isso permite, na maioria das vezes, instalar e desinstalar plugins em tempo de execução.

Aí você me pergunta: *Por que então ele pede para reiniciar?* Bem, a razão é que as coisas na prática quase nunca funcionam tão bem quando prometida na teoria (e isso deveria gerar grande cautela em todos os desenvolvedores ao ler artigos falando sobre as maravilhas da modularidade).

Outro bom exemplo é o sistema em que estou atualmente trabalhando, o JIRA. A Atlassian, que desenvolve o produto há mais de uma década, tem em sua [plataforma](https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/atlassian-platform-common-components/plugin-framework/osgi-spring-and-the-plugin-framework) um gerenciador de plugins que é capaz de instalar e desinstalar plugins OSGi dinamicamente (funciona melhor que no Eclipse, para dizer a verdade). Esse gerenciador também é usado em outros produtos como Confluence e Bamboo.

Para facilitar o desenvolvimento de plugins OSGi para os produtos da Atlassian, o gerenciador de plugins e o [SDK da Atlassian](https://developer.atlassian.com/display/docs/set+up+the+atlassian+plugin+sdk+and+build+a+project) livram você da maior parte dos detalhes complicados do OSGi. Os pontos de extensão do seu plugin ficam num XML chamado `atlassian-plugin.xml`. Claro, XML não é a melhor coisa do mundo, mas é melhor que lidar diretamente com os manifestos OSGi.

O uso de plugins aqui é muito intenso e produtos inteiros como JIRA Portfolio, JIRA Software e JIRA Service Desk são construídos como plugins em cima no JIRA Core.

Sobre o IntelliJ, não encontrei fontes confiáveis, mas não me parece que os módulos dele são OSGi.

## [Java Module System](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/)

Um módulo é uma coleção de códigos e dados que possui um nome. Não é o mesmo que pacote, JAR ou WAR, mas basicamente é como se você pegasse algumas classes e isolasse do resto do mundo.

A ideia é que você possa desenvolver sua aplicação em um ou mais módulos que explicitamente fazem uso de outros módulos, ou seja, suas dependências. O próprio Java vai ser modularizado.

Ante disso, não havia realmente uma divisão entre as classes, a não ser um controle manual via *Class Loaders*. Mas em geral, todos as classes de todos os JARs de uma pasta seriam carregadas em memória sem diferença alguma.

Pacotes possuem apenas uma modularidade muito básica, que é a visibilidade `default`, mas não isola realmente o código ou os dados, nem permite definir dependências entre pacotes.

Agora, você pode explicitamente dizer qual parte do código depende de qual e os benefícios incluem:

- Identificar antecipadamente a falta de dependências
- Permitir que diferentes módulos explicitamente implementem a API de um determinado módulo
- Evitar conflitos entre classes com o nomes pacote e nome, mesmo diferentes versões de uma biblioteca
- Evitar o *Classloader hell*, onde você tem duplicatas, conflitos, dependências circulares e outros problemas entre classes carregadas por diferentes Class Loaders. Na verdade, os módulos também serão implementados usando Class Loaders, mas pelo menos será usando um padrão e não o caos que ocorre hoje.

Tudo isso declarando um módulo como este exemplo:

```
module com.foo.bar {
    requires com.foo.baz;
    exports com.foo.bar.alpha;
    exports com.foo.bar.beta;
}
```

Como tudo em Java, o módulo é compilado para um arquivo `.class` e fica na raiz do pacote.

Não precisa nem de explicação, mas basicamente o `requires` é como um nível mais alto de `import` e o `exports` é análogo ao `public`.

Para que um módulo implemente uma API de outro módulo, existe o `provides`, como no seguindo exemplo:

```
module com.mysql.jdbc {
    requires java.sql;
    requires org.slf4j;
    exports com.mysql.jdbc;
    provides java.sql.Driver with com.mysql.jdbc.Driver;
}
```

Isto permite encontrar implementações SPI mais facilmente e eficientemente.

E outro módulo faz uso da implementação com `uses`, assim:

```
module java.sql {
    requires public java.logging;
    requires public java.xml;
    exports java.sql;
    exports javax.sql;
    exports javax.transaction.xa;
    uses java.sql.Driver;
}
```

Para entender o funcionamento sem entrar em detalhes sobre a implementação, a leitura adicional do [Quick Start](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start) (em Inglês) é altamente recomendável.

Comment: Muito interessante. Eu nunca havia associado plugins com módulos. Também não sabia sobre o `provides`. Parece muito útil! Muito obrigado pelo esclarecimento. :)