# O que são módulos na programação?

Tags: terminologia, engenharia-de-software, programação-modular

Eu sei que existe está pergunta: [O que são módulos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114741/o-que-s%C3%A3o-m%C3%B3dulos)
Porém a explicação não vai direto ao ponto e me deixou confuso, assim como *propriedades, métodos, argumentos* e outras palavras já vi bastante o uso da palavra **módulos**.

Eu gostaria mesmo é de saber a definição da palavra **módulos**, uma explicação bem simples. Assim como dizer que `métodos são funções de classes associadas a um objeto, etc...` com um pequeno exemplo.

Comment: Acho que isso não se aplica a uma linguagem especifica, minha sugestão é trocar as tags atuais por engenharia de software e terminologia, clarooo se isso não mudar o sentido da pergunta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Não há uma definição única. Cada contexto, cada tecnologia pode defini-lo de uma forma distinta. Então a definição do dicionário pode ajudar mais que uma definição específica. Pode ser visto no [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/m%C3%B3dulo) ou [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/index.php?lingua=portugues-portugues&palavra=m%F3dulo), então seria algo medido de forma pequena e harmoniosa?

Existem módulos que não possuem estes nomes. E existem coisas chamadas de módulos que pode não passar por uma inspeção rigorosa do termo.

Note que sequer há uma definição do tamanho desse módulo. Ele pode ter uma responsabilidade bem específica ou ter uma responsabilidade bem mais geral. Ainda que seja certo que ele não corresponde ao todo, ele é uma parte do todo.

Enfim, não há uma boa definição canônica do que seja isto. Tem que analisar o contexto para definir melhor do que está se falando.

## Programação modular

Existe a [programação modular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming) ([veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/223549/101)) que propõe criar aplicações divididas em partes pequenas. O que são essas partes não é bem definido. Um módulo neste contexto pode ser um método, pode ser uma classe, pode ser um arquivo fonte, pode ser um executável, pode ser um pacote, seja lá o que isto signifique em cada situação, pode ser algum outro agrupamento de outras partes menores ainda.

## Classes estáticas

De fato tem linguagem que chama de módulo uma classe que só possui membros estáticos.

## Agrupamento de tipos e outras construções

Tem linguagem que agrupa vários tipos (representados por classes, por exemplo) dentro dele. Em algumas isto assemelha-se a um *namepace*, outras à uma unidade de compilação, em geral até misturando os dois conceitos.

## PHP

Em PHP o termo é usado para coisas que não são da programação em si.

## Fora da programação

Nem passei perto de falar dos módulos usados em algo no ciclo profissional do desenvolvedor, mas não está relacionado à programação em si.

## Matemática

Tão pouco falei do módulo que é a operação de obtenção do resto de uma divisão inteira. Acho que não é o objetivo da pergunta.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: O que é um módulo em ERP (ERPs modulares)? Seria um conjunto de funcionalidades que podem ser adicionadas ao sistema de maneira condicional? Como isso seria implementado? Se for amplo faço nova pergunta, tenho curiosidade de saber sobre a implementação.

Comment: Cada um pode dar i nome que quiser, em geral não há uma definição de engenharia pra isso, é nomenclatura que serve um pouco como marketing (não no sentido de propaganda, mas de dar um limite para uma coisa ou outra, e quem sabe cobrar baseado nisso). Em geral o pessoal tem o módulo financeiro, ou de contas a receber, pagar, bancos e fluxo de caixa, entre outros separados, tem o controle de estoque, que pode ter o custos junto ou não, os livros fiscais, compras, mas que poderia ser um módulo de Supply Chain (embora alguns consideram algo separado do ERP), o PCP, etc.

Comment: E esses módulos, cujo uso pode ser cobrado à parte, costumam ser disponibilizados de que forma? É um monte de `if`s no código? Aí o código checa junto a um servidor se está habilitado para ser usado?

Comment: Não, costuma ser executáveis diferentes, mas tem casos diferentes, pode ser muito mais conceitual. Em geral é comum você ser obrigado comprar um módulo se precisar de um pequeno detalhe dele. Essa é uma área que é mais zoneada que muita coisa que a gente vê.

Answer (score 10):

Módulo é um termo generico para definir uma unidade código ou artefato com uma finalidade especifica, a ideia básica é juntar certos elementos por algum criterio ex coesão. Depois de agrupados esses elementos podem ser distribuidos e facilmente integrados em outros sistemas, exemplos são dlls, jars e até mesmo plugins. Em outras palavras módulos são subsistemas que podem ser agregados a outros sistemas.

Uma classe pode ser 'módulo' no sentido de que sua responsabilidade é resolver um problema bem definido. Um namespace ou pacote seria um exemplo de um conjuto de classes ou funções(depende da tecnologia) que combinadas resolvem determinadas tarefas.