# O que é um módulo no PHP?

Tags: php, terminologia

Estou estudando essa [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.return.php) e me deparei com esse termo:

> A declaração return retorna o controle do programa para o **módulo** que o chamou. A execução continuará na expressão seguinte à invocação do **módulo**.

Comment: Vixe, documentação em português é bem baguncadinha... Espere que alguém te responda :p

Comment: @WallaceMaxters a documentação em inglês tá igual.

Comment: [O que são módulos na programação?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129254/91)

Answer (score 10):

Neste contexto foi uma forma deles generalizarem o local onde a função foi chamada ou onde está o código sendo executado, no caso o `return`, já que ela pode ser chamada de diversos lugares e é possível retornar de qualquer parte do *script*. Pode:

- ser chamada de outra função,
- chamar para resultar em um membro de uma classe,
- chamar direto no *script*.

Entenda que um arquivo de *script* do PHP é como se fosse uma função, então é possível encerrar a execução em qualquer ponto. Se o código pode retornar tanto de uma **função** quanto de um ***script***, que nome usaria para se referenciar à ambos? Eles escolheram módulo.

Um exemplo pode ser visto na resposta do Guilerme Nascimento.

Isto começa ser elucidado logo abaixo na documentação:

> Se chamada no escopo global, a execução do script corrente é finalizada. Se o arquivo de script corrente for incluído ou requerido com as funções include ou or require, o controle é passado de volta ao script que está chamando. Além disso, se o script corrente foi incluído com a função include, o valor informado ao return será retornado como o valor da chamada de include. Se um return for chamado de dentro do script principal, sua execução será finalizada. Se o script corrente for mencionado nas opções de configuração auto_prepend_file ou auto_append_file php.ini, a execução do script será finalizada.

Obviamente que se chama uma função em um arquivo de *script* de outro arquivo de *script* tem algumas implicações constantes na documentação e há exemplos descendo a página. Ele tem que trocar este contexto já que em PHP a aplicação não é uma coisa única como é em linguagens compiladas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 9):

Eu posso estar enganado, mas escolha do termo módulo é para se referir a duas situações aonde o `return` pode ser usado, por exemplo creio que a maioria vai presumir que o `return` é usado em funções, sim de fato está correto:

```
function foo() {
    return 1;
}
```

No entanto o `return` é suportado em PHP pelo `include` e `require` (eventualmente pela primeira chamada do `_once`, mas isto é outra história, depois explico).

Por exemplo se fizer isto:

teste.php:

```
<?php
return 'teste';
```

E chamar assim:

```
<?php
$x = include 'teste.php';
var_dump($x);
```

Vai obter isto:

> string(5) "teste"

Então creio que eles escolheram o nome módulo por este motivo, já que `function` é uma coisa e `include` é outra, internamente (a nível mais baixo) podem até ser "idênticas", mas a nível do PHP são coisas diferentes, então é como se fossem realmente 2 módulos, um script e outro `include`.

Answer (score 5):

## Módulo é o script chamador

A expressão "módulo", nesse contexto, tem significado semelhante a "outro script que não é o próprio arquivo PHP".

Acredito que foi escrito dessa forma porque o `return` tem um uso adicional além do uso comum de retornar o valor quando está dentro de uma função, que é o mesmo comportamento de outras linguagens de programação.

Nesse outro uso do `return`, é comum criar um arquivo PHP, por exemplo, só com configurações e usar o comando `include` para retornar as configurações daquele arquivo.

Por exemplo:

---

### config.php

```
<?php
return [
  'usuario' => 'user123',
  'banco' => 'adm',
  'servidor' => 'locahost'
];
```

---

### busca.php

```
<?php

$config = (require 'config.php');
```