# O que são "unidades de código"?

Tags: terminologia, estilo-de-codificação

Quero saber o que significa unidades de código?

Vi esse termo em uma resposta aqui no SOpt e fiquei em dúvida.

> As unidades de código devem ser curtas e ter apenas uma responsabilidade.

Link da pergunta em que vi o termo >> [O que define um código limpo?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/33702/o-que-define-um-c%C3%B3digo-limpo?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: Editei. Quero saber o que é “unidades de código”, que foi comentado no outro post;

Comment: Acredito que o assunto cai aqui também: [O que são módulos na programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129254/91)

Comment: Acho que seria interessante você colocar um comentário na própria resposta que está la com o link para cá.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> A palavra **unidade** tem origem no termo latim *unitas* e designa a qualidade do que é único ou **indivisível**. Tem como significado aquilo que é considerado de forma individual e não plural.

Os limites físicos de uma unidade de código são conceitos abstratos e variam conforme o contexto. Pode ser uma linha de código, pode ser um grupo delas, uma função, uma classe ou um projeto inteiro. Não tem como definir exatamente onde começa e termina uma unidade de código. Mas o que foi dito na resposta citada é que cada unidade de código deve possuir uma, e somente uma, responsabilidade. É dito unidade, no conceito de indivisível, como citei acima, pois a lógica implementada, indiferente do número de linhas de código, executa apenas uma tarefa muito bem definida.

A título de exemplo é possível considerar uma implementação de classe. Você pode possuir métodos *get/set* de propriedades, assim como métodos de validação dos valores. Seria possível implementar a lógica de validação dentro do método `set`, porém, se dentro de outro método qualquer você precisar validar o valor novamente, você precisará replicar a lógica de validação ou utilizar o método `set`. Nem sempre a segunda opção é indicada, pois pode deixar o código pouco semântico (a entender: você precisa validar um valor, mas utiliza seu respectivo `setter`). O ideal é possuir o método apenas para validação e, dentro do método `set`, invocá-lo para validar o valor. Divisão de responsabilidades para diferentes unidades de código (nesse caso, os métodos).

Answer (score 10):

Ali foi propositalmente deixado vago.

Provavelmente a menor unidade de código seja a [função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122429/101), mas tenho dúvidas sem não há exceções, quem sabe uma [*lambda*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34907/101) que praticamente é uma função.

Também é uma estrutura, uma classe, um [módulo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129254/101), um arquivo de fonte. Cada um com seu nível de influência e com o que deve ser sua responsabilidade. Em geral um vai dentro do outro.

função -> classe -> módulo ou arquivo fonte

Answer (score 10):

Unidades de código são as maneiras que instruções podem ser agrupadas. Isso ajuda na organização e na distruibuição/integração de um projeto. Alguns exemplos são funções, 'módulos', classes.

O termo indica a granularidade de um 'trecho código', assim como (classificamos) as **unidades** de medidas: km, m, cm e mm. O software tem as respectivamente.