# Alguma forma mais pythonica de resolver o problema abaixo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, revisão-de-código, pep8

Crie uma função que retorne o valor da expressão: 2/3 + 3/5 + 4/7 + 5/9 + … + n/m, para um valor de n definido pelo usuário. 
Verifique se o valor de n definido pelo usuário é positivo e, caso não seja, solicite outro valor até ser fornecido um valor positivo.

Como eu resolvi:

```
def expressao():

    expr =0
    n = -1

    while n <0:


        n = int(input("Digite um valor para n: "))
        for i in range(n -1):
              expr += n/(2*n -1)
              n-=1

        return expr
```

Alguma forma mais elegante/pythonica de resolver o problema acima?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sim, tem como ser mais [idiomático](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192343/5878). Pelo enunciado podemos identificar duas ações bastante distintas: ler o número do usuário e calcular a soma da sequência. Fazer isso na mesma função quebra o [princípio de responsabilidade única](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100516/5878), tem grande potencial de infrigir o [DRY](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/120931/5878), gera um elemento que não é uma [unidade de código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216315/5878) e consequentemente quebra a [ortogonalidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195461/5878).

Resumindo, você tem uma função que faz muita coisa, que depende de muita coisa e afeta muita coisa (só seria pior se tivesse um `print` no resultado). E nem começamos a analisar o Python ainda.

Para o cálculo da soma da sua sequência, busque utilizar a função nativa `sum` em conjunto com uma expressão geradora, pois é muito mais fácil de entender o propósito da expressão, isto é, deixa o código legível. Quando se tem um laço de repetição, a primeira coisa que interpretamos é que o código necessitará de todos os elementos da sequência de forma individual, sendo que na verdade nos interessa apenas a soma.

Assim, para uma sequência de `n` elementos, basta fazer:

```py
def sum_of_sequence(n):
  return sum(i/(2*i-1) for i in range(2, n+1))
```

Veja que corrigi o laço para `range(2, n+1)`, pois como estava na pergunta, `n/(2*n-1)`, e variando `n` de forma decremental, faz com que a soma seja calculada de trás para frente, o que é contra-intuitivo e sem justificativa.

> **Nota 1:** seria de responsabilidade da função também validar a sua entrada. Visto que a sequência só existe para n ≥ 2, qualquer valor abaixo disso poderia ser esperado um erro ou retorno nulo, conforme os requisitos da aplicação. Por questões de simplificação optei em não adicionar a validação.
>
> **Nota 2:** dependendo do objetivo, não seria responsabilidade de uma função que calcula a soma gerar a própria sequência; se existisse outras demandas como ter que acessar o n-ésimo termo haveria duplicação de código. Para essa situação provavelmente seria melhor ter uma função responsável apenas por gerar a sequência e outra apenas para somar (a `sum` do Python já faria esse papel).

Como é uma função isolada e só tem uma responsabilidade, podemos testá-la sem depender ou afetar qualquer outra parte do código (ela é ortogonal):

```py
import math

assert math.isclose(sum_of_sequence(2), 2/3)
assert math.isclose(sum_of_sequence(3), 2/3 + 3/5)
assert math.isclose(sum_of_sequence(4), 2/3 + 3/5 + 4/7)
assert math.isclose(sum_of_sequence(5), 2/3 + 3/5 + 4/7 + 5/9)
```

Já para a leitura de `n` por parte do usuário, basta ler um valor da entrada enquanto não for um número positivo (vale lembrar que zero não é positivo).

```py
def read_positive_number():
  while True:
    try:
      number = int(input('Informe um número positivo: '))
      if number > 0:
        return number
    except ValueError:
      continue
```

Outra função que só faz uma coisa. Lembra da ortogonalidade? Pois é, vamos testá-la também sem afetar o resto do sistema nem depender de outras funções. Nesse caso, como dependemos de uma ação do usuário, devemos criar um *mock* que simulará a ação do mesmo.

```
from unittest.mock import patch

# Simula o usuário informando '1'
with patch('builtins.input', side_effect=['1']):
    assert read_positive_number() == 1

# Simula o usuário informando '0' e '2' respectivamente
with patch('builtins.input', side_effect=['0', '2']):
    assert read_positive_number() == 2

# Simula o usuário informando 'a', '-1' e '3' respectivamente
with patch('builtins.input', side_effect=['a', '-1', '3']):
    assert read_positive_number() == 3
```

Desta forma será possível escrever testes unitários para testar código que são, de fato, unidades e, assim, permitirá identificar e manter de forma pontual todo e qualquer problema no sistema. Se uma função parar de funcionar, bastará corrigí-la sem analisar o resto da aplicação. Muito mais prático e fácil para o desenvolvedor e muito mais barato para a empresa.

Portanto, o código ficaria:

```py
n = read_positive_number()

print(sum_of_sequence(n))
```

---

Sobre o seu código:

```py
def expressao():

    expr =0
    n = -1

    while n <0:


        n = int(input("Digite um valor para n: "))
        for i in range(n -1):
              expr += n/(2*n -1)
              n-=1

        return expr
```

Alguns pontos que eu levantaria:

1. O nome da função, `expressao`, não identifica o que a função faz;
2. Valores iniciais "aleatórios" em variáveis; se eu não sei qual é o próposito da função, verei o `n = -1` e perderei um tempo tentando entender porque ela inicia com -1 se há uma condição `n < 0`; em algumas linguagens isso pode até acontecer por ser uma solução fácil, mas no Python temos isso como uma falsa expectativa;
3. É feita a leitura de `n`, mas não é tratado os casos em que a entrada não é numérica;
4. A própria mensagem `"Digite um valor para n: "` não informa ao usuário qual é o tipo de valor que ele deve inserir: número positivo;
5. Se o usuário digitar qualquer valor menor ou igual a 0 o retorno será 0, que não é o esperado;
6. Se você já tem `i` variando de 0 até `n`, por que não utilizá-lo ao invés de decrementar o valor de `n`? Alterar o valor do parâmetro acarretará no que chamamos de perda de informação, pois se você quiser, por exemplo, acompanhar a execução por uma ferramenta de debug, o valor do parâmetro será alterado e você se obriga a memorizar qual era;
7. Há espaçamentos desnecessários no código, o que prejudica a leitura do mesmo;
8. Evite nomear variáveis que não serão utilizadas, como o `i` no seu laço; isso também gera uma falsa expectativa no leitor que o fará analisar quem é `i` e como ele se comporta... para nada; no Python temos como convensão nomear as variáveis de controle não utilizadas como `_`, ficando `for _ in range()`;

Comment: Há um erro na resposta: `n` não é a quantidade de elementos da sequência.

Comment: Woss, corrigido. Obrigado.