# Como programar de maneira modular?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, paradigma-de-programação, programação-modular

Estou estudando alguns conceitos aqui e quero ver se estou com as ideias certas e também lançar uma(s) pergunta(s).

Em programação modular (seja estruturada ou OOP) em vez da minha aplicação ser monolítica ela é dividida em módulos, com interfaces bem definidas entre cada um. Em OOP por exemplo, um módulo seria um determinado grupo de classes.

Uma aplicação modular apresenta vantagens, que no momento não sei dizer exatamente quais são (esta seria uma pergunta, mas não a mais importante das que quero fazer). Se não me falha a memória esses benefícios incluem poder dividir a tarefa de implementar os módulos entre diferentes equipes ou membros de uma equipe e a possibilidade de causar menos impacto quando é feita uma mudança no código (este impacto fica restrito ao módulo).

Muito bem, mas mesmo um módulo individual pode ser quebrado em subpartes, que também podem ser chamadas (ou não?) de módulos. Se não estou enganado, uma classe ou mesmo um procedimento ou método podem ser chamados de módulo.

Bem, o caso é que nesse nível de granularidade (classe ou método) é possível programar de forma modular, com rotinas bem definidas, coesas em relação ao que se propõem a fazer e cuja implementação se mantém em um nível de abstração adequado e consistente (são esses os requisitos para se ter uma rotina modular? Esta é outra pergunta). Por sua vez, essas rotinas podem chamar sub-rotinas igualmente bem definidas.

Como atingir modularização em todos esses níveis de granularidade? No nível da aplicação, dos módulos individuais e no nível das rotinas? Em particular neste último caso, quais seriam algumas heurísticas para se determinar o que uma rotina deve fazer e em qual nível de abstração se manter? Eu apanho muito nessa parte, de subdividir as rotinas, "trafegar" pelos níveis de abstração corretos e delegar funcionalidades a qual sub-rotina.

No caso de OOP a modularização das classes é obtida com encapsulamento, então acredito que basta saber como encapsular (distribuir entre as classes os dados e operações sobre estes dados) corretamente.

Se for muita pergunta, avisem que eu quebro. Talvez indicar qual tópico específico merece uma pergunta à parte.

Comment: Não é muita pergunta porque está relacionado, mas uma delas me parece bem ampla, vou responder o que dá.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<sub>Vou falar aqui de algo que não está bem formalizado e que há correntes diferentes de pensamento. Mais recentemente começou-se definir o assunto de forma diferente do que originalmente fora definido, então tenha em mente isso quando estiver lendo. A resposta serve até para evoluir o tema</sub>

## Programação estruturada e procedural

[Programação estruturada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122430/101) tem a ver com fluxo de código, é algo sobre o algoritmo em si. Talvez esteja falando de [programação procedural](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195069/101), a confusão é comum, deve até ter sido induzido ao erro por outra fontem vejo muitas erradas por aí.

Talvez esteja falando apenas de um aspecto granular da modularidade. Isso nem se contrapõe à orientação a objeto que se preocupa com a organização do código das estruturas de dados e seus comportamentos.

A programação modular melhora a programação procedural e é uma base para a orientação a objeto, e se preocupa desde o código do algoritmo, passando pelo código da estrutura de dados, até a estruturação da solução como um todo.

A programação procedural pode ser estruturada ou não, pode ser monolítica ou modular. No passado era comum se fazer algo monolítico. Em português claro antes se fazia um código "linguição".

A programação procedural já é um pouco modular, mas não é tão enfática na separação de responsabilidades. A modular leva isso para outro patamar, para outras unidades de código.

## Programação modular

Este [paradigma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101) institui principalmente a [separação de responsabilidades](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/178718/101) em módulos.

Não é bem definido o que é um módulo. É uma [unidade de código](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216315/101), então ela prega separar o código em funções.

Claro que essas funções são agrupadas de forma que elas interajam entre si ou operam em cima do mesmo objeto. Chame de módulo, de classe, de estrutura, do que quiser.

Em alguns casos pode precisar de um nível extra de modularização, pode ser que se crie um pacote com uma unidade de compilação em que cada linguagem trata do jeito que achar melhor.

Por isso eu vejo o módulo como algo que segrega código, não só um grupo de classes, conforme a pergunta já entende.

Algumas pessoas podem considerar que um *namespace* é um módulo. Um módulo prevê algum encapsulamento que o *namespace* não provê.

Justamente por prover encapsulamento eu digo que se a orientação a objeto coloca este como ponto único da sua definição então as pessoas deveriam estar dizendo que programam modularmente. Vejo que outros aspectos juntos com este é que formam a orientação a objeto.

Programação modular costuma ter definição de visibilidade de código. [Até C tem isso](http://www.embedded.com/design/prototyping-and-development/4023876/Modular-Programming-in-C), embora poderia ser melhor. C não é o melhor exemplo para o paradigma.

Me parece óbvio que códigos que sejam pequenos e que só fazem uma coisa são mais legíveis e fáceis de dar manutenção. Juntando que ele precisa que fique encapsulado e não exponha detalhes que os seus consumidores não precisam saber. Diminuir a área de impacto em uma alteração é um objetivo da programação modular e a pergunta está certa nisso.

Por isso usa-se o termo interface. No sentido de contrato mesmo, como até é em OO, mas o mecanismo não precisa ser o mesmo. Pegue C e os seus arquivos de cabeçalhos que possuem interfaces, ainda que não costumamos chamar assim. Sim, é um pouco diferente, mas é um contrato com as [assinaturas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101).

A pergunta fala em [**coesão**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101) e isso é muito importante. Eu tenho um livro que fala disso e ele foi escrito antes de alguém pronunciar orientação a objeto.

**Abstrações adequadas** são importantes na programação modular, e é claro que elas devem ser consistentes. Não é que isto defina a PM, é só questão de importância.

## Como modularizar

Modularizar não tem regra clara, é aquele tipo de coisa que dá para definir abstratamente ou mostrar um caso concreto. É muito difícil ensinar, dar regras específicas de como fazer isso. As perguntas mais específicas eu não saberia responder facilmente, e até acho que para isso precisaria de um capítulo de um livro, o que torna a pergunta ampla.

Mas é igual à orientação a objeto, a diferença é que a programação modular não define acoplamentos por herança e ela em si não prevê polimorfismo, o que nada impede que o mecanismo seja usado junto com ela e frequentemente é em linguagens mais modernas, como Rust e Go, só pra ficar nas mais badaladas ultimamente.

Então assim como em OO, programação modular não tem regras claras do "tamanho" do módulo, é analisar o problema, entendê-lo, modelar, refinar, aprender com o s seus erros e dos outros e ir melhorando.

Na maior parte do tempo faço programação imperativa com modular. Eventualmente transpasso para OO. Embora tem momento que é mais fácil dizer que é OO já que o paradigma modular não pegou tração. Tudo é uma questão de marketing. E o que importa é a engenharia. No fim o nome correto importa pouco.

## Vantagens da modularização

As vantagens de sua adoção são principalmente essas vendidas em OO, não tem diferença, por isso que eu falo que muita gente programa modularmente mas pra não ficar fora da moda diz que programa OO, até por ela nem saber o que é PM.

Existe a escola de OO que se prende às abstrações, modelagem de código, em padrões de projeto e não nos mecanismos próprios de OO e tudo o que esta escola fala no fundo está falando de PM sem saber, um dos motivos porque não gosto desta escola e não confio, neste ponto, em quem defende isso.

## PM é diferente de OO

PM não incentiva a associação de estado com comportamento, mas também não impede. As linguagens mais modernas estão evitando um pouco isso dando mecanismos melhores de segregação e nem tanto de junção. Em OO tem regras que são até conflitantes. Hora dizem para juntar tudo, hora dizem para separar.

A prática mostrou que juntar demais pode tornar a ideia mais fácil de entender, mas torna a manutenção mais difícil, por isso que em banco de dados muitas vezes pensamos em modelo lógico e modelo físico. Projeto orientado a objeto é uma coisa e poucas pessoas fazem, programação orientada a objeto é outra bem diferente e se usar OOD para programar não fica bom.

Sempre falo que as pessoas adotam coisas que elas leem, e não aquilo que elas conhecem. Se ela conhecesse todos os fundamentos ela saberia o que ela está fazendo. Mas também não adianta ficar tentando impor a nomenclatura certa em toda conversa sobre o assunto.

A maioria do que você aprende em OO na verdade está aprendendo PM (ou MOP em inglês) e acho trágico que geralmente a pessoa que está ensinando não sabe disso.

Também uma parte do que se fala de *modular oriented programming* é só a programação procedural.

Existem paradigmas que são antagônicos, outros são complementares, alguns possuem relação hierarquica, por isso pode haver uma certa confusão.

## Sempre é confuso

Ajuda na confusão o fato de OO ser *hype* e PM estar no escanteio. Então tem definições menos estruturadas, menos debates, menos divulgação.

Fiz uma pesquisa para responder e vi que tem algumas bobagens sobre o assunto, não só porque a base consolidada sobre o tema não fala sobre algumas coisas que estão falando por aí, mas também porque algumas, ou não fazem sentido, ou "roubam" de outros paradigmas, ou estão claramente errados.

Isso inclui o [artigo da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming), que tem seu mérito em algumas partes. Leia a primeira seção. A seção de aspectos chaves tem algo útil, mas não tudo, e o primeiro parágrafo da seção de história é muito boa, esqueça o resto a não ser por curiosidade.

A [Wiki de Portland](http://wiki.c2.com/?ModularProgramming) é sempre um lugar que gera bons debates. As pessoas não concordam, mas evoluem o entendimento ali. Eu discordo de várias coisas nela, mas é útil se souber interpretar textos.

Essa ideia de que um módulo é só uma unidade de compilação não me agrada e contrapõe partes do artigo, um dos problemas de texto wiki.

## Conclusão

A pergunta tem entendimento bem acima da média, pelo AP quase não precisava. Espero que as pessoas entendam que modularização é bom em qualquer projeto que não seja um *script* simples, mais ainda em soluções *enterprise*. Orientação a objeto é boa em alguns casos, como complemento à modularização.

Como OO não deixa de ser modular o termo é mais pomposo, pode continuar dizendo que faz OO quando só faz PM. Mas evite dizer que faz OO quando mal faz procedural direito, quando erra no imperativo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Era procedural mesmo, desculpe. Sobre a parte de OO gostaria de ler mais a respeito de situações em que a segregação é promovida em oposição ao encapsulamento, e sobre as linguagens que suportam esse comportamento. Teria alguma indicação?

Comment: A segregação e encapsulamento são ortogonais, espero não ter passado a impressão que não são. É que o pessoa exagera no encapsulamento e acha que tudo que diz respeito ao objeto deve estar dentro dele. Hoje métodos de extensão, implementação padrão em interface, mixins, traits e coisas assim são mais adotados onde é possível, que de certa forma é a volta de usar funções soltas como ra no procedural. Ok, de forma mais modular, com mais significado, com mecanismo melhores. Mas ficou claro que juntar tudo não era bom, Pra solucionar isso começam criar um monte de classes, a maioria sem sentido.

Comment: Proponentes de OOP se prendem muito à conceitos estabelecidos mais que procuram mecanismos adequados para cada caso. E era pior, foi melhorando, hoje muita gente que era mais radical com OOP é menos hoje, o que mostra que eles estão dançando em um terreno escorregadio. Por isso que não me prendo muito à paradigmas, padrões de projeto. Eu vou atrás da melhor solução e se uma linguagem não me fornece eu quero que forneça. Pena que poucas *mainstream* estão fornecendo mecanismo melhores.

Comment: _"se usar OOD para programar não fica bom"_ - você está dizendo que existe um gap entre OOD e implementação? E se for isso mesmo, você considera esse "não fica bom" um fato consumado ou seria mais para uma opinião?

Comment: _"muita gente que era mais radical com OOP é menos hoje, o que mostra que eles estão dançando em um terreno escorregadio"_ - essa parte também eu gostaria que falasse de uma forma mais específica, se possível.

Comment: @Piovezan como eu não tenho provas, eu vou dizer que é minha opinião, mas tem vários indícios. Design tudo fica lindo, na hora de criar o código sempre começa perceber que não encaixa, a não ser que já tenha feito algo idêntico. Eu vejo muitos desenvolvedores que sempre fazem a mesma coisa a vida toda, o que eu acho um erro. Eu diria que hoje a maioria do software existente no mundo é duplicata sem necessidade. Quem sempre cria algo novo sempre se enrosca n hora de implementar. Meu teclado está falhando, depois respondo mais. Se eu esquecer, me avise.

Comment: Está aí o lembrete. :) Pensando bem faz todo o sentido esse gap, que deve ser no mínimo do tamanho da distância entre o modelo e a linguagem de programação.

Comment: Esse é o mesmo motivo que acvho que o TDD é falho.  e porque algumas APIs são estranhas. É feito um *design*  lindo que na hora de implementar se mostra ruim e acaba ficando esquisito. Curiosamente o tal do *design* é contra o Agile. E muitas pessoas que fazer o *design* antes de programar só defensores do Agile. EU não entendo como é isso. Parece que acada um tem sua própria definição do que é Agile. Sou a favor de planejamento não um *design*  antes de programar, porque na hora que está fazendo vai percebendo que "não é bem assim que funciona". A não ser que já conheça os desafios daquilo...

Comment: ... o que só ocorre quando você já fez aquilo. E se já fez porque vai fazer de novo? Eu percebo muita duplicação de esforços. Tem muita gente que é produtiva pelo simples fato que está sempre fazendo as mesmas coisas. Então na verdade isso é improdutividade, toda repetição é improdutiva.

Comment: No começo de OOP muita gente defendia as ideias básicas do paradigma como se só pudesse fazer daquela forma, aos poucos os mais pragmáticos começaram abandonar um pouco certas ideias, ou pelo menos só usar quando era necessários. Algumas pessoas continuam fazendo porque OO manda fazer assim. Note que estou falando de quem conhece o assunto, não estou falando de quem sequer entende o que é OO. Herança é um desses casos que viram que trazia problemas e em alguns casos útil de fato. Encapsular tudo pode ser bom para o *design*, mas não para performance, essas coisas precisam ser olhadas.

Comment: Se pegar os textos de cada época você vê que tem variação na forma de pensar das pessoas, o ganho de cada elementos de OOP não é algo tão concreto e vai precisando de ajustes. Hoje tem muita gente que chegou no posso certo de entendimento do que é útil e quando. Claro que sempre tem quem fica no que aprendeu e não muda o pensamento. Se tá bom pra eles, tudo bem.

Comment: Obrigado pelos esclarecimentos. Sem querer me delongar mas uma pergunta agora sobre modular, [nesta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18037873/2241463) do SOen é dito: _"Your modules can be implemented as classes (...) However, modules are meant to be logically separate pieces of the programs and as such it doesn't make sense to have them as classes, as you can have many different objects of a class. If I was to write a modular system and use classes for modules, I'd make them all singletons"_. Quando você programa de maneira modular em OOP deve seguir esse caminho, correto? Faz sentido?

Comment: Então programação modular é uma coisa e poucas pessoas entendem isso, criar módulo que é parecido com um pacote, um *namespace* ou esse módulo que tem no Java 9 é outra completamente diferente. Esse modular é criar compartimentos em um sentido amplo, é ter partes estanques, é ter separações claras do que é cada coisa.