# O que são componentes de software?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, terminologia, engenharia-de-software, componentes

"Componente" é uma palavra usada em vários contextos e com isso imagino que fique difícil definir genericamente.

Por definição é uma parte que compõe um todo. Por exemplo, um subsistema.

Fala-se também que componentes são reutilizáveis. Fala-se também em "arquiteturas componentizáveis" ou "componentizadas".

Do [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-a-software-component) retirei a seguinte definição, que ajudou até certo ponto.

> Um componente é um sistema autocontido que tem um ou mais canais de entrada e um ou mais canais de saída. Sem as entradas ele não tem nada para fazer. Sem as saídas ele não pode servir a um propósito.
>
> Observe que uma função recebe entrada através de seus argumentos e retorna um resultado, então ela também tem entradas e saídas. Assim que recebe uma entrada ela retorna uma saída. A entrada e saída caminham sempre casadas.
>
> Um componente verdadeiro pode se comportar dessa maneira também, mas os canais de entrada e saída podem também operar independentemente um do outro - isto é, as saídas não precisam caminhar casadas com as entradas.
>
> O ponto essencial é que um componente pode receber entradas de um ou mais canais e enviar saídas para um ou mais canais, mas o que acontece entre essas operações é escondido das vistas. As preocupações do componente são todas dele mesmo - uma caixa preta para o mundo. Tudo o que o mundo exige é um contrato (do que ele precisa e o que ele fornece) através do qual algum uso pode ser feito dele em um sistema maior de componentes ligados.
>
> Um típico *DVD player* é um componente. Ele recebe entrada através de um DVD inserido em sua gaveta e do seu controle remoto e retorna saídas de áudio e vídeo. Um componente de software não é diferente; entretanto, deve-se notar que seus canais de entrada/saída são tipicamente assíncronos.

Enfim, o que são componentes?

Quais exemplos do âmbito do software podemos usar para ilustrar os mesmos?

Quando sei que estou desenvolvendo um componente?

Comment: Relaciondas: [O que são “unidades de código”?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/216315/91) e [O que são módulos na programação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/129254/91)

Comment: Relacionada: [Is there a difference between a component and a module?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/178927/93338)

Comment: Me parece que componentes e módulos são conceitos fáceis de confundir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A definição "oficial" dada numa conferência sobre Componentes em 1996 é:
*"Um componente é uma unidade de composição com interfaces especificadas contratualmente e com dependências de contexto explícitas apenas Um componente de software pode ser implantado [deployed] de forma independente e está sujeito à composição por terceiros".*

Basicamente componentes de software é um pedaço de software independente, mas que pode ser usado por outros softwares. 
Se assemelha muito a uma biblioteca, ou seja, uma pessoa cria um componente para acessar um banco de dados. Ao invés de eu criar uma classe ou um código para fazer o acesso ao banco de dados, eu incluo esse componente com o código já criado para fazer acesso ao meu banco de dados. 
É um subconjunto de um software porque pode ser reutilizado, pode estar contido em um software, mas independente porque funciona também sozinho/ separado de outros sistemas. Componentes de software são focados em reutilização.
Este link da UFCG dá o conceito por diversos autores (incluindo a definição que coloquei):
http://www.dsc.ufcg.edu.br/~jacques/cursos/map/html/comp/definicoes.htm 
Já neste link dá o mesmo exemplo que eu citei:
https://www.componentsource.com/pt-br/help-support/about-us/components .
Lá está escrito assim no subtítulo **CBD (Component-Based Development)**:
*"Por exemplo, se um programador criar um componente para acessar um cliente em um banco de dados corporativo, nenhum outro programador terá que escrever tal funcionalidade novamente."*

Por fim este link também fala como ela supri as deficiências do desenvolvimento com paradigma de POO, que é o mais bem aceito atualmente: https://www.maxwell.vrac.puc-rio.br/5244/5244_3.PDF

Comment: Parece que toquei num assunto que rescende a um certo mofo...  componentes CORBA... coisa incomum de se ver... Isso me levanta a dúvida, alguém aqui já mexeu com componentes CORBA alguma vez? Se disser que são componentes gerais alguns vão dizer que sim, mas CORBA acredito que quase ninguém...

Comment: Pergunto isso para entender se componentes têm uso habitual dentro dessa definição que foi passada. Não é uma pergunta dirigida ao autor da resposta.